# Implement cyclic flows in android apps

Tags: android, android-fragments

We need to implement cyclic flows in android like when user is  on flow A he can go to flow B, From flow B to flow C and Flow C to Flow A.

A->B->C->B->A...

How we can achieve this considering we have stack size limitation, also when we have to use fragments.

Comment: In activity you can use intent to open next activity, while in fragment you can replace the fragment of the container

Comment: Yes, I know that but what about stack size it keeps on increasing as we repeat flow cycle. I need to know how we generally implement cyclic flow in android.